# Safe way of redefining \- only for math mode

Tags: macros, etoolbox, robust-commands

I know that `\-` is already used for hyphenation and inside `tabbing`. How can I patch this command such that it does something else, **but only inside math environments?** I tried the following:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, preview]{article}  % standalone, preview, varwidth=10cm
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xparse, blindtext, etoolbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\let\hyphen\-\relax
\def\here{XXXXXXXXXXXX}
%\renewcommand{\-}{\relax\ifmmode(my cmd)\else\hyphen\fi\here}
%\renewrobustcmd{\-}{\relax\ifmmode(my cmd)\else\hyphen\fi\here}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\-}{}{\relax\ifmmode(my cmd)\else\hyphen\fi\here}
\begin{document}
a\-b  $a\-b$
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

However I observed some weird effects:

- the `\renewcommand` and `\renewrobustcmd` generally yield the same results, but with `\RenewDocumentCommand` sometimes things go out of margin.
- when using the `standalone` class, weird things happen:

  - when using `preview` option, none of the commands work as intendent and the `RenewDocumentCommand` version even throws an error `! Argument of \OT1\" has an extra }`
  - without `preview` (remove blindtext) everything works as intended

What the heck is going on?

Comment: I can't test now but beware that `\-` is robust, so a simple `\let\hyphen\-` won't do what you probably think.

Comment: Also `\protect\def` means nothing (in that place `\protect` is just `\relax`), maybe you meant `\protected\def`.

Comment: @campa ok, I changed it for `etoolbox`'s `renewrobustcmd`. To be honest my knowledge of low level TeX is rather limited.

Comment: If what you want is a one-character command, the digits are there for use in such a situation.  So maybe `\0` for the "narrow" minus.

Answer (score 3):

You *might* do as follows, but I'm not recommending it.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\robustify\-
\let\latex@hyphen\-
\renewrobustcmd{\-}{%
  \ifmmode
   (my cmd)%
  \else
   \expandafter\latex@hyphen
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

a\-b

$a\-b$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please refresh my memory: this works because `\-` has been declared by `\DeclareRobustCommand`, so `\robustify` replaces the LaTeX protection mechanics by the low-level etex one, and that's why `\let` works. Or am I as usual completely off?

Comment: @campa You're right.

Comment: I guess one could use `letltxmacro` as an alternative?

Comment: @frougon That's more complicated for several reasons.

Comment: @egreg Can you please tell a bit more? The example appears to work with `\LetLtxMacro{\latex@hyphen}{\-}`.

Comment: @frougon Yes, but not if you use `\DeclareRobustCommand\-{...}` to renew the definition.

Comment: @egreg Ah, right. I guess the `\LetLtxMacro` and `\DeclareRobustCommand` mechanisms interfere when used on commands with the same name. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @egreg I actually made a new question regarding this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529433/definitive-way-to-patch-commands

Answer (score 0):

I was unhappy with the previous answer, as it doesn't work in all circumstances (e.g. inside tikz-nodes). In a last ditch effort, after trying `etoolbox`'s `\appto` and variants to no avail, I tried the "brute force" approach: copy paste and edit the source code from the LaTeX2e manual.

```latex
% original definition in LaTeX2e
\DeclareRobustCommand{\-}{%
  \discretionary{%
    \char \ifnum\hyphenchar\font<\z@
      \defaulthyphenchar
    \else
      \hyphenchar\font
    \fi
  }{}{}%
  \fi
}
```

It works like a charm (demo below). The big disadvantage is of course that, should the LaTeX2e source change, the change isn't carried over automatically. This raises the question:

> Is there any way in LaTeX to achieve 100% the same behaviour without having to copy paste the source?

**EDIT:** I posted this a new question: [Definitive way to pre- and append code to commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529433) it seems like there is not (!)

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  % also works in [preview]standalone
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext, tikz}
\usepackage{xparse, etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\hyphen{\textbf{(hyphen)}}
\def\mycmd{\textbf{(my cmd)}}

\makeatletter
\undef{\-}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\-}{%
  \ifmmode
    \mycmd
  \else
  %\@dischyph%
  \discretionary{%
    \char \ifnum\hyphenchar\font<\z@
      \defaulthyphenchar
    \else
      \hyphenchar\font
    \fi
  }{}{}%
    \hyphen% (just for debugging purpose)
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\par text\-text 
\par $math\-math$
\par $\text{text inside math \- text inside math}$
\section*{sections: test\-test $math\-math$}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] at (0,0) {tikz node};
\node[draw] at (6,0) {text\-text $math\-math$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{text\-text $math\-math$}
\end{figure}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: the original definition is available as `\@dischyph` you don't need to copy the code

Comment: @DavidCarlisle if I do that I get `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].` in the provided example.

Comment: then you did something wrong (you need to avide using the same internal name for the robust command)  But in anycase the strongly recommended solution here is _not_ to patch `\-`  it is much better to use a new name for the new functionality. TeX being a macro expansion language you can rewrite anything at any point but it's a power best avoided if you want the resulting documents to be readable by humans, anyone seeing `\-` in a tex file (and not having read every line of code in your macro files) will assume that `\-` means what any tex tutorial says it means.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle not sure what I did wrong then, all I did was replace the lines `\discretionary...` up to `\hyphen` with `\@dischyph`. Regarding your second point, I don't think anyone will miss hyphenation in math mode, and it will be very obvious what the macro will be doing in the end (a modified minus sign -- hence I really want only a 1 character macro. At the moment I use `\p` and `\m` but those are **less** readable honestly).